# Retrieving conversations from Samsung Grand :Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, samsung-mobile

Hi I am developing android SMS app where I am trying to retrieve messages from built in messaging app and display it on a `listview`. I am using the below code for retrieving conversations.

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
```

This is working fine on all phones except Samsung Grand. I am getting exception as

```
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MyApp/com.example.MyApp.MainActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at com.example.MyApp.MainActivity.getSMS(MainActivity.java:188) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at com.example.MyApp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206) 08-23 
 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074) 
 08-23 11:29:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    ... 11 more
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
  private ImageView Msg;
  private ImageView Home;
  ListView listviewsms;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Msg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.createmessage);
    Msg.setOnClickListener(this);

    Home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
    Home.setOnClickListener(this);

    listviewsms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSMS);

    final List<String> msgList = getSMS();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.conversation_list,R.id.name,msgList); 

    // updating listview
    listviewsms.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getSMS()
   {
    ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, String[] {"*"}, null, null, "date desc");

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        String read = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("read"));           

        //to fetch the contact name of the conversation
        String contactName = address;
        Uri Nameuri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));  
        Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(Nameuri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);

        if(cs.getCount()>0)
        {
            cs.moveToFirst();
            contactName = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }           
        sms.add(contactName + "\n"+body);

     }

    for (int i = 0; i < sms.size(); i++) 
    {
        Log.e(" "," "+sms.get(i));
    }

    return sms;
    }
     public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //button functionality
    }
 }
```

How do I resolve this.
Please Help.
Thanks!

Comment: have you add permission for it? And what is your Target SDK?

Comment: And this is because you should check Target API...

Comment: Target Sdk is 17 and I have given the read permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

Comment: never add any link of any other web, if it is broken in future then question becomes useless for future use

Comment: add complete MainActivity class to ur question .bcoz I also faced similar problem on samsung Google nexes so I may solve ur problem

Comment: @sanjana did you try my answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For samsung phones you need to use this uri `Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");`

And do not pass `null` as the projection.

Add `new String[] {"*"}` as the projection.

Comment: Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true") should work for samsung devices. In this case you wont get thread_id but _id. SO my question is did you get the same NPE when you tried this URI?

Comment: I tried the above code with Async .Now I get a different error as  http://txtup.co/HpRWV

Comment: Right, this URI worked. Problem is with your cursor columns that you are trying to access. Do one thing, print the column names by cursor.getColumnNames() and check if you are accessing the right columns.

Comment: `Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 16 columns.` This clearly says you got 2 results from the query with 16 columns. But you accessed the wrong column index.

Comment: Ya.My phone has two messages i.e 2 rows.but How do I solve this

Comment: Told you what to do. Print the columnnames

Comment: You need to tell me how you are accessing the columns.. My guess is you are trying to access thread_id.

Comment: http://txtup.co/brujN This is what I have tried and I am getting same Async Error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36163/discussion-between-tarun-and-sanjana)

Comment: What is line number 207 at com.example.MyApp.MainActivity.getSMS(MainActivity.java:207)??

Comment: http://txtup.co/zcXSm  This is what I am trying on line number 207.If u are around can we converse on chat

Comment: can we discuss on chat

Comment: ya I am able to retrieve it by content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses.

Comment: Ok. great. How are you differentiating between samsung and other phones?

Comment: This is also found using the new Telephony APIs present in KitKat. As is this a public API, I have raised this as a bug with Google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71848&thanks=71848&ts=1403126924