# retrieving messaging conversations

Tags: android, sms, uri, projection

I am working on a messaging android app. I have a listview of messages and I want to show conversation when I click on an item (I mean I want to show all the messages that I received from special contact and messages I send to it) I found this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035970/i-want-to-fetch-and-view-sms-conversations)

but I have problems with these lines of code since I don't know anything about content provider concept:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

what does **{"*"}** part mean in the second line?
and why we are giving **String[]projection** as a projection to query method?

Answer (score 0):

I read that I should not pass null to projection part cause it creates error so I should pass `new String[]{"*"}` and the app won't stop.
here is the 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395988/retrieving-conversations-from-samsung-grand-android)
where I find this answer.